# eclipse java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for nonexisting class

Tags: java, eclipse

When I try to compile my project I got this error:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: me/hansolox1/tetris/test
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.hansolox1.tetris.test
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main"
```

but class me.hansolox1.tetris.test I deleted beafore I added real code to project.
it's first time I see an error like this... Please help!

EDIT:

I have deleted test class but new class with method 'main':

```
package me.hansolox1.tetris;

import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;
import org.newdawn.slick.state.StateBasedGame;

public class tetris extends StateBasedGame {
    public static final int MAINMENU = 0;
    public static final int TETRIS = 1;

    public tetris(){
        super("Tetris!");
    }

    @Override
    public void initStatesList(GameContainer arg0) throws SlickException {
        this.addState(new MainMenu(MAINMENU));
        this.addState(new MainState(TETRIS));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SlickException{
        AppGameContainer app = new AppGameContainer(new tetris());

        app.setDisplayMode(800, 600, false);
        app.start();
    }
}
```

I'm using slick2d engine...

EDIT2: I also have tried cleanup

Comment: Please post your code (SSCCE) so we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: You might try a Project Clean or Refresh the project if you deleted on the file system and Eclipse hasn't picked up the change.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the properties page of the project
2. Go to Run/Debug Settings
3. If you found the deleted class there, delete it again.

This works for me!

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try the -clean option on the eclipse command line. That cleans up the stored project information, including what classes are affected by a change to another class.

Answer (score 0):

My working solution:

1. Made new project
2. Copied all files from orginal project to new project
3. Deleted old project after testing new one

I know that this is probably the worst solution, but it worked...